# How to store text box value to be passed to getJson request as query parameter

Tags: javascript

I need to be able to store the text value of a search box term, which can be used as a query parameter in a getJson request. I'm appending the search term to the end of the url the user is taken to after hitting the enter key, but the issue is that on the location replacement, it shows up as an error because the url for the page is `/faq/search-results/`.

```
$(".faq-search").keyup(function(e){
   if(e.which == 13) {
        window.location.replace("/faq/search-results/" + $(".faq-search").text());
   }
});
```

Once the user has been sent to the search results page, I have a script which, if the user is on that url, is supposed to grab the search term from the pathname in the url, and submit it as a query parameter to the getJson request:

```
    if(window.location.pathname == "/faq/search-results/"){
    $("document").ready(function(e) {
    var url = window.location.pathname;
    var exp = url.split(/^(([^:\/?#]+):)?(\/\/([^\/?#]*))?([^?#]*)(\?([^#]*))?(#(.*))?/);
    var question = exp[5].split("/")[3];
    $.getJSON("//search.url-to-search.com?q=" + question + "&results_type=faq", {
    },
        //Get results and make 'em look good
        function(data) {
            console.log(data);
                $.each(data.data, function(i, data) {
                    if(data.type === "FAQ"){
                     $(".faq-results").append("<li class='result-item'><a href=\"" + data.permalink + "\"><h3>" + data.title + "</h3><p class=\"content\">" + data.text + "</p></a><p class=\"category\">" + data.type + "</p></li>");
                    }
            });
         });
});     
}
```

I believe the issue is that it won't fire off the request because its looking for only `/faq/search-results/`. I think I need a way to store the search term as a variable and pass it as a query parameter, but not sure how to accomplish this, as I believe it would make the variable out of scope.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of things are wrong in your code:

first to collect the input value use .val() note text().

Secondly you are not passing the input value as a  query string you are adding it to the url path /helloWorld. I think it is better to add as a query string ?q=helloworld.

I have therefore adjusted your code, removed your code to extract the text from the path and implemented a function to extract a named query param, this function is called getParameterByName.

The code below should be pretty much self explanatory.

```
$("document").ready(function(e) {
  // 
  // Collects the input param as passes it as a query string note
  // ?q= our string
  //
  $(".faq-search").keyup(function(e) {
    if (e.which == 13) {
      window.location.assign("file:///C:/Users/spydre/Desktop/text.html?q=" + $(".faq-search").val());
    }
  });

  // snippet gets a query param from url 
  function getParameterByName(name, url) {
    if (!url) {
      url = window.location.href;
    }
    name = name.replace(/[\[\]]/g, "\\$&");
    var regex = new RegExp("[?&]" + name + "(=([^&#]*)|&|#|$)"),
      results = regex.exec(url);
    if (!results) return null;
    if (!results[2]) return '';
    return decodeURIComponent(results[2].replace(/\+/g, " "));
  }

  // collect any query string param whos name is q
  var question = getParameterByName("q");
  if (question) {

    // pass question to our getJson
    $.getJSON("//search.url-to-search.com?q=" + question + "&results_type=faq", {},
      //Get results and make 'em look good 
      function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        $.each(data.data, function(i, data) {
          if (data.type === "FAQ") {
            $(".faq-results").append("<li class='result-item'><a href=\"" + data.permalink + "\"><h3>" + data.title + "</h3><p class=\"content\">" + data.text + "</p></a><p class=\"category\">" + data.type + "</p></li>");
          }
        });
      });



  } //if question 

})
```

Comment: I modified the conditional to `if(window.location.pathname.indexOf("/faq/search-results/")>-1)`, but this still doesn't allow the script to grab the value from the textbox and send it as the query parameter. The search is happening, but its not passing the search term into the url to search.

Comment: Sorry. So what you are saying is the url in the address bar does not show your query string when the enter button is pressed?

Comment: That is happening as well, but what I need to be able to do, is pass the value in the text box as a query parameter to the search url.

Comment: At the moment you are appending it as part of the path search-results/MY-SEARCH-TERM. If you want to append it as a query param you need "faq/search-results?q="  + $(".faq-search").text() But then your code to extract it is incorrect. Can you try and clarify, so i can help.

Comment: Also your better off using window.location.asign(...) rather that replace.

Comment: So I need to pass the value from the text box from the search page, on to the url in the conditional if you're on the search results page, which fires the getJson request for the search results. How can I correctly either store the search parameter to be used by the search results page, or pass it correctly into the url to be extracted by the search results page and send the getJson request with the search term appended as a query parameter?

Comment: Are both your segments of code on the same page. Or do you have a page with the input box that is then changing the url to a new page with the search code?

Comment: The search box is on a separate page. When the user hits the enter key, they are then sent to the results page. So I need to be able to pass the search term to the results page to get the correct url for the getJson request with the search parameter.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141803/discussion-between-martinwebb-and-matt).

Comment: After our discussions the solution now works and my answer has been updated.